# Periodically screen capture web page in remote server

Tags: php, automation, server, screenshot, html

I have a web page hosted in a linux server with cpanel.
My page contain and display information continually update.
I need to do an automatic screen capture (jpg or png) of the page directly in the server (a location accesible via URL) every 10 seconds - "offline" - also when the page is not open in any browser.
Is possible?
I have available a lot of web application in the cpanel, any can do this?
Or I need a php script running in the server?
Please help.

Comment: do you test curl command get content of web page ? for take screen you should use [bash](http://askubuntu.com/questions/202391/bash-script-to-take-screenshot-and-save-the-image-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is actually use some sort of pdf class, and then setup a script (cron job) that could call the page, put the current results into a pdf, and then save it on the server at the time intervals you would like.

The server would execute the script on it's own, and no need to have a browser open. The only problem with that tho is that if you are storing pdfs on the server at a 10 second interval, that's 6 pdfs per minute, x 60 minutes, x 24 hours which would equal over 8k pdfs for a single day.

Comment: Thank a lot for the answer. Can you explain more about the script (cron job)?

Comment: I need only a JPG (the last) in the server, because i need to retry this file from a program that not support to display html. And i need JPG format or PNG. So, any 10 seconds the pic is overtired. This is my specific need but, obviously, the pdf idea is good to do a record info but with an interval more big.